Mapbox GL Weird Border on Content Button
I'm using the react-map-gl Popup component and daisyui to display the following daisyui card wrapped in the Popup. For some reason when the card is displayed within the Pupup there is a weird border around the button as shown in the left image below. As soon as I open up the browser dev tools to try to troubleshoot the CSS code to figure out what is causing the border to show up it goes away as shown in the below image on the right. Can someone help me figure out how to perm. remove that border?
    <div
      className={`card card-compact bg-base-100 image-full w-52 shadow-xl`}
      onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter}
      onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}
    >
      <figure>
        <img
          src={
            spotData.media
              ? `https://aytfgqpbho.cloudimg.io/v7/${spotData.media}?force_format=webp&q=50&w=400`
              : 'https://aytfgqpbho.cloudimg.io/v7/https://public-assets.fishhop.com/default-spot-picture.jpg'
          }
          alt={spotData.name}
        />
      </figure>
      <div className="card-body">
        <h2 className="card-title">{spotData.name}</h2>

        <div className="card-actions justify-end bottom-0 right-0 absolute m-2">
          <button className="btn btn-primary btn-sm">View Details</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



It looks like the default outline, you shouldn't remove it as it's indicating that the element is focused.
You can simulate it with dev tools but using :focus-visible in the ":hov" menu
